# calculating execution time in c++ and always getting zero

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having a trouble calculating the execution time in c++ i used both the chrono an ctime library but every time I run the code i get zero no matter how large is the input size this is the last I tried :

```
int main()
{  
LARGE_INTEGER freq,t1,t2;
double elapsedtime;
int s = 1000000;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

int *arr = new int[s];
int random;

srand(time(NULL));
random = rand() % s;
for (int i = 0; i <s; i++)
    arr[i] = i;


QueryPerformanceFrequency(&t1);


cout << binarySearch(arr, 0, s-1,random)<<endl;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&t2);

elapsedtime = (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart)*100.0 / freq.QuadPart;

cout << "time :" <<elapsedtime<<endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

The time is still zero .

Comment: I tried using nanoseconds instead of millisecond but it didn't work too.

Comment: what is `QueryPerformanceFrequency` ?

Comment: Is that because the optimiser got rid of the loop for you and that it really isn't taking any time; or is it because it really is taking time but your elapsed time is 0?

Comment: For reference : [QueryPerformanceFrequency function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You certainly meant to use `QueryPerformanceCounter` instead of `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. `QueryPerformanceFrequency` always returns the same value. Though be aware that there is [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux when in doubt read the manual huh?

Comment: `QueryPerformanceFrequency` should be called only once to obtain amount of ticks in second so the results of `QueryPerformanceCounter` can be converted to normal time.

Comment: Again and again, ppl keep calling `c++` instead of `c`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I changed it .Thanks it's working now.

Comment: @SmitYcyken: It's not even clear, what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: @SmitYcyken: This is undoubtedly a C++ question, since `std::cout` isn't available in C.

Comment: @Smit The code is C++ but in fact I would tag it with winapi only because the question is a pure winapi matter.

Comment: "`srand(time(NULL));
random = rand() % s;`" - this is horrible in so many ways. 1) `time()` only has second resolution. 2)  the size of the seed is *tiny* (32 bits). 3) the quality of random numbers returned by `rand()` is horrible. 4) that modulo (`%`) is introducing bias.  There's a better way: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 4):

[QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905.aspx)

> Retrieves the frequency of the performance counter. The frequency of the performance counter is fixed at system boot and is consistent across all processors.

If you call that API call twice, and subtract the returned values, it evaluates to zero.

To determine the time between two points in time, you need to call [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx):

```
LARGE_INTEGER t1{ 0 };
::QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);

// Code to measure

LARGE_INTEGER t2{ 0 };
::QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

auto elapsed_time_in_mu_s = (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) * 1000000 / freq.QuadPart;
```